# Delete records that match a regular expression using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

For the life of me I cannot get this part of my Linux assignment to work. This is the requirement:

So far we have:

> ```
> grep -iv chevy cars
> ```
>
> Now let's delete the cars that are $10,000 or more.  Pipe the output of
>   the grep into a sed to do this, by deleting records that match a regular
>   expression representing 5 (or more) digits at the end of a record (DO NOT
>   use a repetition factor, such as `{5}`, for this):

I feel like it should be:

```
grep -iv 'chevy' cars | sed '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*/ d'
```

I've tried many solutions already on here.. and nothing is working.

Input Data:

```
plym    fury    77      73      2500  
chevy   nova    79      60      3000  
ford    mustang 65      45      17000  
volvo   gl      78      102     9850  
ford    ltd     83      15      10500  
Chevy   nova    80      50      3500  
fiat    600     65      115     450  
honda   accord  81      30      6000  
ford    thundbd 84      10      17000  
toyota  tercel  82      180     750  
chevy   impala  65      85      1550  
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

Comment: can we see a sample of the input data.

Comment: Added the input data

Comment: What about that `sed` command isn't working exactly?

Comment: I have no idea.. The problem is part of a Linux program and it is not accepting my input

Comment: What do you mean "not accepting my input"?

Comment: @EtanReisner The assignment I'm completing is being run on a program created by my professor. The correct input (ie the correct command) must be entered for the program to continue. I feel that I have the command correct, but it may just not match his exact required input. Extremely frustrating.

Comment: In that case try removing the SPACE between SLASH and d ...

Comment: Have you tried running that command locally? Does it do what you expect? Do you see the difference in your attempt and the posted answer?

Comment: @ChrisDiMatteo: really hard to say what prof wants from you <grin> ... next suggestion is to finish the *off with a $ to anchor it to the end of line; after all I don't know whether any of the other numeric columns might ever reach 5 digits (which you presumably **wouldn't** want to suppress).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring what your professor's program expects exactly, these requirements (must not begin with "chevy" or "Chevy", must not end with a number with 5 or more digits) would also fit into a single sed command:

```
$ sed '/^[Cc]hevy/d;/[[:digit:]]\{5,\}$/d' cars
plym    fury    77      73      2500
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
fiat    600     65      115     450
honda   accord  81      30      6000
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

or a single grep command:

```
$ grep -vi '^chevy\|[[:digit:]]\{5,\}$' cars
plym    fury    77      73      2500
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
fiat    600     65      115     450
honda   accord  81      30      6000
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

<sub>The actual input contains blanks at the end of the lines, so the commands above wouldn't actually work. If these blanks are real and not just a result of copy-pasting, they would have to be taken into account as follows:</sub>

```
sed '/^[Cc]hevy/d;/[[:digit:]]\{5,\}[[:blank:]]*$/d' cars
```

and

```
grep -vi '^chevy\|[[:digit:]]\{5,\}[[:blank:]]*$' cars
```

Comment: Maybe add `$` to constrain the final number regex to the last column?  (Assuming that's dollars, not miles! :-)

Comment: @tripleee I did this at first, but the input in the question has (spurious?) blanks at the end of the lines... will update to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing one lot of [0-9]:

```
grep -vi chevy cars| sed '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*$/d'
plym fury 77 73 2500
volvo gl 78 102 9850
fiat 600 65 115 450
honda accord 81 30 6000
toyota tercel 82 180 750
ford bronco 83 25 9525
```

does what you want.  anything with five or more digits got omitted.

Comment: Though the regex you *actually* want is probably simply `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[root@kintuparantu tmp]# awk '$5<10000' aaaaaaa.csv
plym    fury    77      73      2500  
chevy   nova    79      60      3000  
volvo   gl      78      102     9850  
Chevy   nova    80      50      3500  
fiat    600     65      115     450  
honda   accord  81      30      6000  
toyota  tercel  82      180     750  
chevy   impala  65      85      1550  
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

Answer (score 0):

**cars:**

```
plym    fury    77      73      2500  
chevy   nova    79      60      3000  
ford    mustang 65      45      17000  
volvo   gl      78      102     9850  
ford    ltd     83      15      10500  
Chevy   nova    80      50      3500  
fiat    600     65      115     450  
honda   accord  81      30      6000  
ford    thundbd 84      10      17000  
toyota  tercel  82      180     750  
chevy   impala  65      85      1550  
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

Try this:

```
$ grep -iv 'chevy' cars | sed -r '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+/d'
```

**Output:**

```
plym    fury    77      73      2500  
volvo   gl      78      102     9850  
fiat    600     65      115     450  
honda   accord  81      30      6000  
toyota  tercel  82      180     750  
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$5 < 10000 && !/[Cc]hevy/' file 
    plym    fury    77      73      2500  
    volvo   gl      78      102     9850  
    fiat    600     65      115     450  
    honda   accord  81      30      6000  
    toyota  tercel  82      180     750  
    ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```